# Set cronjob to start at 9am and every 3 hours

Tags: cron

How do I set a cronjob to start at 9am and run every 3 hours?
I have this `0 9/3 * * *` but it's giving me an error.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `9-24/3`?

Comment: @thebjorn it would be 0 9-24/3 * * * ?

Comment: That's what I would try (I don't have a *nix system handy right now to test)